# Drawing a Line with MouseAdapter Not Showing Java

Tags: java, graphics, line, draw, mouselistener

Found this sample code which should produce a drawn line after clicking, but does not show anything or works. Assume all import statements are correct, code gives no errors and I have no idea why it would not work. The line color is red while the background is white so it should show clearly if it works. The mouse listener seems to be correct as well. Any reason why this code will not work?

```
public class PathPanel extends JPanel {

/**
 * The panel width.
 */
public static final int WIDTH = 400;

/**
 * The panel height.
 */
public static final int HEIGHT = 400;

/**
 * The background color of the panel.
 */
public static final Color BACKGROUND_COLOR = Color.WHITE;

/**
 * The color to paint with.
 */
public static final Color FOREGROUND_COLOR = Color.RED;

/**
 * The line width.
 */
public static final int LINE_WIDTH = 8;

// Instance Fields

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -3644129903653409515L;

/**
 * The path being created.
 */
private final Path2D myPath;

// OR you could use Path2D.Double instead of GeneralPath

// Constructor

/**
 * Constructs a new general path panel.
 */
public PathPanel() {
    super();
    myPath = new GeneralPath();
    myPath.setWindingRule(GeneralPath.WIND_EVEN_ODD);

    //myPath = new Path2D.Double();

    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    setBackground(BACKGROUND_COLOR);
    addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener());
}

/**
 * Paints the current path.
 * 
 * @param theGraphics The graphics context to use for painting.
 */
@Override
public void paintComponent(final Graphics theGraphics) {
    super.paintComponent(theGraphics);
    final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) theGraphics;

    g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                         RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    g2d.setPaint(FOREGROUND_COLOR);
    g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(LINE_WIDTH));
    g2d.draw(myPath);
}

// Main Method

/**
 * Creates and displays a GeneralPathPanel.
 * 
 * @param theArgs Command line arguments (ignored).
 */
public static void main(final String... theArgs) {
    final PathPanel panel = new PathPanel();
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("GeneralPathPanel Demo");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

// Inner Class

/**
 * Listens for mouse clicks, to draw on our panel.
 */
private class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
    /**
     * Handles a click event.
     * 
     * @param theEvent The event.
     */
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(final MouseEvent theEvent) {

        if (myPath.getCurrentPoint() == null) {
            myPath.moveTo(theEvent.getX(), theEvent.getY());
        } else if (theEvent.getClickCount() == 2) {
            myPath.closePath();
        } else {
            myPath.lineTo(theEvent.getX(), theEvent.getY());
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The Sample Code you posted works fine for me. Have you tried to add a `System.out.println()` in the `mouseClicked(final MouseEvent theEvent)` Method to check if it is actually called? If it is not called, you could try to change it to `mouseReleased`.

The imports I used:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
```